Values are not saved in the graph after converting it into an image
I’ve been working to integrate a print function for my PyQt desktop app program where the users can print a document with the generated graphs added on it. Before I do that, I need to find a way to save the graphs as images. After many attempts, I only managed to print out images of the graphs before the data was to be added, even though I saved these images right after adding the values from a CSV file into the graph. However, I'm having some kind of issue of converting the graphs into images.
Here's what the graph should look like.
When I save the graph as an image, however, the values (the colored bars) are not present. How can I fix this?
I'm using PyQt for my program.
Here's what I used to create the graph as Well as saving and displaying the graph as an image:
def create_temp_chart(self):
        if not self.fileName:
            return
        low = QtChart.QBarSet("min")
        high = QtChart.QBarSet("max")
        ltemp = []
        htemp = []

        with open(self.fileName) as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            header_found = False
            for row in csvreader:
                if row[0] == "MinTemp":
                    header_found = True
                    continue
                if header_found:
                    ltemp.append(float(row[0]))
                    htemp.append(float(row[1]))
                if len(ltemp) >= 12:
                    break  # Assuming only the first 12 months of data are needed

        low.append(ltemp)
        high.append(htemp)

        series = QtChart.QStackedBarSeries()
        series.append(low)
        series.append(high)

        chart = QtChart.QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Muestra de Temperatura en Celsius")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.AnimationOption.SeriesAnimations)

        category = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

        axisX = QtChart.QBarCategoryAxis()
        axisX.append(category)
        axisX.setTitleText("Mes")
        chart.addAxis(axisX, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
        axisY = QtChart.QValueAxis()
        axisY.setRange(-52, 52)
        axisY.setTitleText("Temperatura en Celsius")
        chart.addAxis(axisY, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        series.attachAxis(axisX)
        series.attachAxis(axisY)

        self.ui.chart_view_temp = QtChart.QChartView(chart)
        self.ui.chart_view_temp.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
        self.ui.chart_view_temp.chart().setTheme(QtChart.QChart.ChartTheme.ChartThemeDark)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.ui.chart_view_temp.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.ui.chart_view_temp.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.ui.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ui.chart_view_temp)
        self.ui.frame_18.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: transparent")

        # Save chart as image
        self.save_chart_as_image(self.ui.chart_view_temp, "temp_chart.png")

     def save_chart_as_image(self, chart_view, file_name):
        QApplication.processEvents() 

        image = QImage(chart_view.size(), QImage.Format.Format_ARGB32)
        painter = QPainter(image)
        chart_view.render(painter)
        painter.end()
        image.save(file_name)

        # Display the image after saving
        self.display_image(file_name)

    def display_image(self, file_path):
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        dialog.setWindowTitle("Chart Image")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap(file_path)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        dialog.setLayout(layout)
        dialog.exec_()

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here or if it's the way I'm designing the graphs.

Some time might be necessary when adding a complex widget as QChartView (which is a QGraphicsView, a scroll area) to a layout, and simply processing events may not be enough, as some events may be added to the next loop iteration. That said, it's not clear if you're actually adding the chart to the layout because you need it in the UI, or if you are going to delete it right after creating the image. In the first case, you should probably use a QTimer to let the layout properly adjust itself, otherwise you should not add the chart view at all, and you could instead directly render the scene.

Post a [mre] including a sample data. Anyway, it seems the cause is the animation option. Try to remove the chart.setAnimationOptions(...) call.
